# OAuth Vs SAML for Modern Web and Native apps

Tags: oauth, saml, openid-connect

I am at a point in a project where I might be needed to bring to table concerns/reasons why OAuth (or even OpenID Connect) should be taken up as the way to go for any future Web and Native Apps over using SAML.

The documentation I have gone through makes the case for the simplicity of OAuth (to which I can attest) but doesn't say it cannot be done in SAML. I've worked with OAuth and I can attest to it's simlpicity but not with SAML that much, but still know that it can be done using SAML, but I think it's way more complicated in that case.

Can anyone point me to an authoritative source that can make that claim and produce any numbers/documentation in favor of OAuth ?

Comment: OAuth is not well-suited for non-web applications (desktop and mobile ones), as the browser is required in all real-world schemes.

Comment: Is that not also true for SAML?

Comment: Put up some reason 10 Reasons Why OpenID Connect (https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/10%20Reasons%20Why%20OpenID%20Connect)

Answer (score 2):

SAML and WS-Fed are enterprise protocols. They have complicated cryptography standards. In the most used profiles, they require browser functionality since the protocol is driven via browser redirects. The token used is a SAML token, XML based and can be large.

If you want to federate with SaaS applications e.g. Salesforce, Workday they only support SAML.

SAML and WS-Fed support SOAP and WCF, no web API.

OAuth is a light-weight protocol suitable for native devices (headless, desktop, WPF), mobile applications etc. There is no browser functionality here so SAML etc. cannot be used. Also these devices are not suitable for complex cryptography

OAuth has a range of profiles e.g. authorization code grant (where OpenID Connect comes into play) and client confidential (that depends on mutual knowledge of a secret key).

It supports web API only.

The token used is JWT - far less bandwidth.

The choice is by use case. One is not "better" than the other.

Refer the scenarios here - [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/#application-types-and-scenarios).

Comment: SalesForce supports OpenID connect. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&language=en_US%22